# Does PHPMailer with oauth2-google use get_oauth_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, phpmailer

We’ve implemented PHPMailer with oauth2-google (via GitHub): no problem.

But I am trying to understand the logic behind the use of the get_oauth_token grant code.
When run standalone, it simply ‘loops’ to the authorization endpoint and back to get an authorization token and then uses this to request an access token and a refresh token from the token endpoint. Developer then pastes the refresh token as a parameter in the instantiation of PHPMailer’s OAuth wrapper class. All very straightforward.

My puzzle is whether:

- get_oauth_token.php is then used by PHPMailer OAuth plus theLeague’s OAuth-client

or

- whether the latter get authorization and access tokens (and if necessary a new refresh token) themselves without calling get_oauth_token.

The redirectURI  (i.e. the URI of get_oauth_token) is not passed to the Google provider instantiation in the PHPMailer published example, and our working (so far...) implementation doesn’t do so either. So I assume it doesn’t use get_oauth_token or any similar callback mechanism since the redirect URI necessary would need to be defined in advance to Google Developer console in the way it is for get_oauth_token itself. But thephpleague / oauth2-google's Readme.md indicates that one *should* be specified.

However …  theLeague’s OAuth-client’s Abstract Provider class includes a  __construct to set some options that include  redirectUri. Later on in getAuthorizationParameters it sets a redirectUri if one hasn’t been provided, and redirectUri  is used in e.g GetAcccessToken.

Can anyone shed light on exactly how redirectURI is being used in this context?

Comment: `get_oauth_token` is only need once, when you initially set up your script. Once you have the refresh token, you're all set. As you may have noticed, HTTP operations (such as OAuth callbacks) are not applicable within SMTP. Beyond that, I'm not the one to ask about OAuth, but it sounds like the OAuth client has support for handling callbacks itself, though PHPMailer isn't using that.

Answer (score 1):

The `redirectUri` is required in order for Google to redirect back to the originating website to complete the OAuth transaction, after the user logs into Google. Once the access and refresh tokens are available, the `redirectUri` will (probably) never be used, unless the refresh token is invalidated.

I don't understand what any of this has to do with PHPMailer, so I can't answer that part of the question.